# Better data structure for faster reads in Map of Map of Map of Lists

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, collections

I've a scenario where I need to store the **map of map of map of list** of data hierarchy for processing in memory. And, currently I m thinking to implement the data structure as

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<Integer, List<String> > > >
```

and the concretes types are,

```
HashMap<stdIdInt, HashMap<libraryNameStr, HashMap<topicIdInt, ArrayList<bookNameStr> > > >
```

As I do not need to maintain any particular order, I m also thinking to replace `List` with `Set` (`HashSet`) which potentially can increase the performance.

Though I've tried till now, I also think using Google' Guava [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is a viable alternate, but I m not sure.

***Background:*** I need to store the details of *each student*'s *id* & their interested *book names* information categorised by their *topic type* which will be further organised by *library names*. I need to process the data & display book names mostly by student id and other times by library name & topic type. And once the book name is shown to the user, I need to delete that entry from the *book names* list.

**The data structure needs to hold & process thousands of entries at high rate** and will hold the data for longer time.

Please suggest an approach or another data structure for faster processing, and **about the type of the data structure/collection class and their usage combination.**

*(please note that the scenario I described above is not exact case, but I tried my best to abstract the complexity of the data hierarchy)*

Comment: What does "high rate" and "long time" mean?  This is all starting to sound like a database to me.

Comment: @skaffman The requests will come ~1000+/sec at peak time and that data will be maintained for around a day, after which new data will come for next day. Yes, I m trying to the stuff supposed to be done at DB as every time hitting the DB is overkill being known that all the data is needed for just processing, but not for permanent storage.

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization.  I would take @Tomasz's suggestion to improve the abstraction, then determine if the data structure performs adequately with some benchmarking.  If it doesn't, identify the part that's too slow and improve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a lot of abstractions here. The rule of thumb is: *every time a collection holds another collection, intermediate object should be introduced*.

In your case this is my suggested OO design:

```
class Student {
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, Library> libraries;
    private getLibrary(int id) {return libraries.get(id);}
}

class Library {
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, Topic> topics;
    private getTopic(int id) {return topics.get(id);}
}

class Topic {
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, Book> books;
    private getBook(int id) {return books.get(id);}
}

class Book {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

And usage:

```
Map<Integer, Student> students = //...
students.get(6).getLibrary(5).getTopic(4).getBook(3)
```

Of course this code needs a lot of further improvements. E.g. you shouldn't need more than one `.` in a line. But it's already much more readable than:

```
students.get(6).get(5).get(4).get(3)
```

Comment: I totally agree with you that I've abstracted the complexity than it required. I do have similar OO design. But my doubt is about the type of the data structure/collection class and their usage combination

Comment: I suppose `Topic` needs to have `List<String>` or `List<Book>` for book names

Comment: I ended up using List with similar VOs as later I found I required to iterate over the list again and again.